# How can I stop scrolling when i focus in UIWebview

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have an iOS app use a `UIWebView`, and there are some textfield views on the `UIWebview's` scrollview, when I focus in `UIWebview` after focus in textfield, the view will scroll and the keyboard will jump, it is terrible.

what can i do?